# Prepopulate a CKEditor form with jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, ckeditor

I'm trying to make images from an HTML table of one cell with a background image and some inserted text above that cell, using CKEditor. I'm find out that if I place the `<textarea>` tags outside the table, then the user is capable of deleting that table. But if I instead place the tags inside the cell, then there's no way I can use my own style for the table (the background image is inserted with css). 
Is it possible to prepopulate an instance of CKEditor with some html and made it uneditable?

Comment: Sounds very complicated. Could you expand a little on what you want to achieve? It's hard to understand what you want (at least for me). I think the real answer to this is a different method of solving your problem than loading the table into CKEditor. Try to describe the underlying problem a little more (unless someone else figures it out).

Comment: Sure, what I want is a simpler way to edit images without having to use a graphical web tool design, and much more limited on its functions. In fact, I'm only required to write text over the image, thats all. So I thought to create a table of one cell, put a background image on it, and with ckeditor write some text over that image (and then send the html and convert it as an image)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the table cell editable and not editable at the same time. And that's basically what you're trying to achieve :).

Instead, load the data into simplest possible editor initialised on `<p>` or `<div>` and write a plugin for changing background of the editable element.

You will also need to think how to write the background settings to data and read them when loading data. That's also a reason why you can't achieve this result with default CKEditor features - the editable tag is not part of the data. But you can write your plugin which will do that.

The easiest solution I can think off would be to:

1. Listen to [`editor#setData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-setData) to grap the background settings from the data (and modify the data if need be).
2. Listen to [`editor#dataReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-dataReady) to apply these background settings to [`editor.editable()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable).
3. Listen to [`editor#getData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-getData) to add information about the background settings to data.